# Unable to assign variable in bash. get command not found error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

When trying to do the following (Assign variable in bash), get the following error:

```
$ a=b
a=b: Command not found
```

I have no spaces at all as you can see but still get the error.

Comment: Are you sure you're running in `bash`?

Comment: You get that error in `csh`, but not in `bash`

Comment: and a "Boooh!" for using screenshots.

Comment: If you're using csh, you set a variable with `set a = b`

Comment: I am using csl2 server to connect to a bash shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this lol :

```
$ csh
$ a=b
a=b: Command not found.

$ bash
$ a=b
$ echo $a
```